# scrapy xpath which is better add_value from common selectors or add_xpath from full response

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I have to scrap some website which is having html content similar like this

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="desc">
    description data
  </div>
  <div id="details">
    <div class="title">title</div>
    <div class="writer">writer name</div>
    <div class="release">12/12/12</div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Here div with id 'details' have many useful content ,and some useful content are out side also

what will be the good practice in parse function

1) use loader.add_xpath for all items

```
sel = Selector(response)
loader = ItemLoader(selector=sel)
loader.add_xpath("title", 'title_xpath_to_get_item_from_full_response')
loader.add_xpath("writer", 'writer_xpath_to_get_item_from_full_response')
loader.add_xpath("description ", 'description _xpath_to_get_item_from_full_response')
```

2) find some common node and define xpath relative to that node

```
sel = Selector(response)
loader = ItemLoader(selector=sel)
common = sel.xpath('xpath_for_div_id_details')
title= common .xpath('./title_xpath_to_get_item_from_common').extract()[0]
loader.add_value('title', title)
writer= common .xpath('./writer_xpath_to_get_item_from_common').extract()[0]
loader.add_value('writer', writer)
loader.add_xpath("description ", 'description _xpath_to_get_item_from_full_response')
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the proposed approaches is in fact minimal. Since you could include the `div[@id='']` in the first version also (which would be highly suggested or otherwise you could end up with wrong data), the results are the same. The only difference can be in code readability and speed of execution. I would go with the first approach when you have a clear structure and the XPath expression is not too long to fit in one line. The other approach should be a bit faster so if you have a significant amount of data to process, I would suggest the second approach (i.e. there are many pages with many items in the details and the pages itself are large, so using a sub-selector *should* be slightly faster).